# Posting XML to webapi is only binding non-collection properties on the [FromBody]request model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

(*Initial question solved but in the update section below, I have questions about why what I've done works*)

We have a asp.net webApi project with a single POST operation that previously only needed to take a request formatted as JSON and would respond with whatever the accept header said (be it application/xml or application/json).

Now the POST needs to be able to accept XML as the request.  This should just be a matter of setting content-type to application/xml and all should be good.

However, the model binding isn't quite working, it's working partly but not all

Here's a simplified version of the model:

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class PostModel
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Identifier", Order = 0)]
        [Required]
        public string Identifier { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "ReturnNullItems", Order = 1)]
        public bool? ReturnNullItems { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "RequestedItems", Order = 2)]
        [Required]
        public List<string> RequestedItems { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Mileage", Order = 3)]
        public int Mileage { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's a simplified version of the controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<ResponseMessageResult> Post([FromBody]PostModel postModel)
    {

        var formatter = GetMediaTypeFormatter();

        if (postModel == null)
        {
            var message = new ErrorMessage { Message = "Malformed Request"};
            return GetResponseMessageResult(message, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, formatter);
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var message = new ErrorMessage { Message = string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage)) };
            return GetResponseMessageResult(message, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, formatter);
        }
    }
```

Here's a sample bit of body xml from the request:

```
<PostModel>
   <Identifier>ya05fom</Identifier>
   <ReturnNullItems>false</ReturnNullItems>
   <RequestedItems>
      <string>EngineCapacity</string>
      <string>FuelType</string>
      <string>ForwardGears</string>
      <string>Transmission</string>   
   </RequestedItems>
   <Mileage>20000</Mileage>
</PostModel>
```

What we're seeing is that in postModel, the Identifer, ReturnNullItems and Mileage properties, which are all simple properties, are bound but the RequestedItems property which is collection property is not.

So in the postModel we'd see:

- postModel.Identifer       -> "ya05fom"
- postModel.ReturnNullItems -> false
- postModel.Mileage         -> 20000
- **postModel.RequestItems    -> null**

The RequestItems property is null.  I've tried having that property be a List  of string and an string Array and neither works.

So this looks like there's an issue binding the nested child elements in the xml to a collection property in the PostModel class but I simply am at a loss as to what I'm missing.

**UPDATE**:

Thanks to Matt G in the comments, his comment gave me a nudge as to what to look at in the .net documentation and that gave me a nudge as to what to try.

Previously I had to add an XmlMediaTypeFormatter to the formatters on GlabalConfiguration:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
```

There was also this below commented out:

```
//var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
//xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

I commented the above two lines back in and voila it works.

I'm guessing that I'm telling the deserialiser to use the `System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter` to deserialise the request body.  I also guess that the default DataContractSerialiser doesn't do the job of deserialising xml with hierarchical xml very well without some extra information (which I don't know how to give).

So now it works but I only have guesses as to how and/or why.  Can any body point me in the right direction or let me know why what I've done has fixed it?

Comment: Try adding attribute `[XmlArray(ElementName = "RequestedItems")]` to the `RequestedItems` property in `PostModel` class

Comment: @Matt G Thank you; didn't solve my problem but did give me a hint as to where I should look.  Updated my question above.